# Como llamar a columnas vacias en MYSQL

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos

Tengo una base de datos en la cual ingreso las actividades de la semana, por region y por tipo de trabajo.
pero resulta que cuando hago la consulta a la base de datos

```
select region,semana,tipo_trabajo,count(*) from trabajos group by region,semana,tipo_trabajo
```

me muestra asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero lo que busco es que tambien me muestren los valores que talvez no se tengan almacenados, como en esta segunda imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero como podria ser la consulta para que me muestren los valores cero "0"

mi tabla "trabajos" es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: deberia mostrar los ceros.... esos registros existen en esa tabla en 0? deberiamos ver los datos de entrada

Comment: Para hacer lo que pides, idealmente, deberías contar con una tabla de `region` otra de `semana` y otra de `tipo_trabajo`, ¿cuentas con esta información? ¿podrías compartir ejemplos de esta tablas?

Comment: Por favor muestrános la descripción de tu tabla **trabajos**

Comment: en mi tabla trabajos solo tengo las siguientes columnas: id/tipo_trabajo/descripcion/region/fecha/semana/

Comment: @PatricioMoracho lo que mencionas es que tenga una tabla para region, otra para semana y otra para tipo de trabajo... pero como deberia llamarlas y que me  salgan lo que necesito

Comment: Exactamente, te he respondido en el escenario que no tengas estas tablas. Si las tienes por favor agrega esta información a la pregunta.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho como deberia realizar, acabo de mandar un capturazo de mi tabla "trabajos", como se ve es una tabla simple, pero me mencionas que lo ideal seria que tenga una tabla de semana, otra de region y otra de tipo_trabajo..como haria eso?

Comment: Por ejemplo, tienes en tu base de datos una tabla maestra con todas las regiones?

Comment: no tengo, pero normal la puedo crear, si es que eso ayuda a resolver lo que estoy solicitando. Asimismo puedo crear una tabla para numero de semana y para tipo de trabajos

Comment: El problema es que si tienes que crearlas, las vas a tener que mantener, cada vez que aparezca una nueva semana, un nuevo tipo de trabajo una región deberías actualizar estas tablas.  Sin duda ayudan para la consulta, pero también puedes partir de la misma tabla `trabajos`, revisa mi última edición en mi respuesta por si te ayuda.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho esa tabla tiene serios problemas de normalizacion y por eso estas viendo esos problemas.

Comment: @Kevincs7 esa tabla, salvo que estes trabajando en un DW (y si no sabes que es, la respuesta es no), **esta mal** Tipo de trabajo y region deberian ser id y los contenidos estar en otra tabla. de esa forma, lo que te dice Patricio que tenes que hacer, sale solo, sin necesidad de lo que vas a tener que hacer para arreglarlo. Te recomendaria con urgencia que leas sobre normalizacion de bases de datos (Tercera forma normal).

Comment: Sin duda @gbianchi, de hecho digamos que ni quiera esta normalizada. Es casi una tabla de Log.

Comment: si, se que la tabla no esta presentando la normalizacion correcta,  creando las dos tablas, una de region y otro de tipo de trabajo, como seria la consulta para que salga lo solicitado

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Por lo que entiendo, en primer lugar, necesitas hacer un producto cartesiano entre todas las combinaciones posibles de `region`, `semana` y `tipo_trabajo`. Y sobre esto completar aquellas combinaciones que tengan efectivamente filas en `trabajo`.

Normalmente para hacer esto, deberías trabajar con tablas maestras para las `regiones`, `semanas` y `tipos_trabajos`, sino las tienes, una forma que puede llegar a ser poco óptima en términos de performance y que solo te permite generar las combinaciones que se puedan heredar de `trabajos` y no todas las realmente posibles, podría ser, construir un producto cartesiano sobre los valores de cada columna de la propia tabla `trabajos`:

```
SELECT  pc.region,
        pc.semana,
        pc.tipo_trabajo,
        IFNULL(count(t.id),0)
    FROM (SELECT *
            FROM (select region from trabajos group by region) t1
            CROSS JOIN (select semana from trabajos group by semana) t2
            CROSS JOIN (select tipo_trabajo from trabajos group by tipo_trabajo) t3
        ) pc
    LEFT JOIN trabajos t
        ON pc.region = t.region
        AND pc.semana = t.semana
        AND pc.tipo_trabajo = t.tipo_trabajo
    GROUP BY pc.region,
             pc.semana,
             pc.tipo_trabajo
```

Comment: realize esta consulta, y me salio como en mi primera imagen

Comment: @Kevincs7, es posible, prueba los cambios que le incorporé a la consulta

Answer (score -1):

Debes usar la función de sql `COALESCE()`. Entonces tu consulta quedaría así.

```
select region,semana,tipo_trabajo, coalesce(count(*), 0) as num_trabajos from trabajos group by region,semana,tipo_trabajo
```

Puedes leer aquí la descripción de la función `COALESCE()`

https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_sqlserver_coalesce.asp

Saludos

Usa esta otra propuesta

```
select region,semana,tipo_trabajo,count(num_trabajos) AS num_trabajos 
from trabajos 
group by region,semana,tipo_trabajo
Having num_trabajos > 0;
```

Comment: estaba viendo el link, pero a lo que me refiero es que esos valores saldran cero porque no existen en los registros, hago la consulta que me mencionas y me sigue saliendo lo mismo, habra otra manera?

Comment: @Kevincs7 por eso te dejamos comentarios para que nos muestres los datos de entrada!

Comment: @Kevincs7 exacto, eso es lo que necesitamos, tu pregunta no está bien enfocada a lo que quieres lograr. Al hacer un `count(*)` y despues un `group by` por algún campo es posible que se devuelva cero para los casos que no contengas region, semana...etc. Debes mostrar las relaciones entre tus tablas para poder ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Las dos propuestas que propones, estan **MAL**. no se pueden contar registros que no existen.